# Can `use std::io` break my code after update of `rustc`?

Tags: rust, using, rust-2021

I'm learning rust for fun after C++ class and I'm wondering, can `use std::io` break my code after update of `rustc` edition to newer?

For example, in C++ using `using namespace std` is bad, because if new function gets added to `std` your multiple translation units code may break after compiler update because of function with name same as function written by you was added to namespace `std`.

However in all the official rust tutorials `use std::io` is used.

Can `use std::io` break my code in rust?

Comment: ?? that doesn't really make sense, the rust imports still have to be namespace qualified unless you import specific identifiers. I haven't used C++ in about a decade but IIRC `using namespace std;` is bad because imports all the symbols into your current scope without qualification. N.B. you can use a star import in Rust, which would suffer from the same issue potentially although nothing in Rust is as massive as `std` in C++.

Comment: @JaredSmith okay, but if we need to create crate called `io` (for example we are writing some sort of parser/whatever) and put some functions in it it might break?

Comment: Firstly, just no. Do not name crates after the modules in the standard library. Secondly, just don't ever use star imports and you'll be fine.

Comment: So convention is just not to name crate after parts of `std` and/or not using star imports?

Comment: General guidelines for rust imports can be found in the [Rust style guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/style/imports.html). There are mentions of `extern crate` in there but nowadays those are automatically added to your source code by `cargo` for your declared dependencies. For this exact reason, it is not recommended to use `*` imports so that new functions/types do not lead to any conflicts.

Comment: @blonded04 there's no reason that you couldn't name a crate `io`, any difficulty derived from that could be caused between any two crates/modules and I've never encountered problems like that in practice. You can always disambiguate the crate with `::io` if there were actually a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `use std::io;` on its own cannot break your code between versions. That declaration only brings the `io` name into scope and that won't change.

If you had done `use std::io::*;`, that would bring everything from the `io` module into scope similar to `use namespace std;` in C++ and thus *could* break your code in the future, but wildcard imports are discouraged in general for that reason.